# UITableViewCell Font Size Array vs String

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8

I ended up creating a prototype cell in my table, and added tags for two labels in there. When I retrieved the label by tag, and specified text for it (hard coded), it displayed properly. When I grab the value from an NSMutableArray, however, and try to display it, it comes out, but at a larger font size. The other styling on the label gets respected (such as color).

Here is my code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    var lblTitle:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(7) as UILabel
    var lblAmount:UILabel = cell.viewWithTag(8) as UILabel

    lblTitle.text = reportData[indexPath.row] as NSString //ignores my label font size of 13, but preserves the color?? 
    lblAmount.text = "$5151.55" //HARD CODED VALUE - respects my font size of 13

    return cell
}
```

Any idea why it would keep the color styling on my label, but whenever I retrieve the value from the nsmutablearray above, it uses a standard font size (much larger) than what I set on the label?

Would love to hear some opinions on what I'm not considering / doing right. I was wondering if maybe the font is stretching somehow but that doesn't explain why it then works for hard-coded strings.

Comment: Do you get the same result if you reverse which label is hard coded (hard code lblTitle's text and use the array value for lblAmount's text)?

Answer (score 0):

A strange bug. First thing I want to tell that I'm not much familiar with the syntax of Swift language but good in Objective C. 
Solution suggestions: Just write the code to set the font size (your required) programmatically after get the reference of UILabels. May be this can resolve your problem of can help you to debug the problem.

You can do it like this:

```
label.font = UIFont(name: label.font.fontName, size: 20)
```

This will use the same font. 20 can be whatever size you want of course.